# Taper off connections nicely in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, nlb, iis-8.5

Is there any mechanism in IIS 8.5 where you can taper off the current connections?

The scenario is that you have two servers that are Network Load Balanced by forward facing hardware. You do not have access or direct control over the NLB. You wish to take a server offline, but you do not wish to kill any connections, just prevent new connections from occurring and wait for current connections to die.

Comment: Looks like stopping each individual website might be the answer I couldn't find any documentation from Microsoft on this (sigh), so I'll have to test it out.

Comment: The answer is sort of works. I've not much experience with hardware  NLB configuration but it looks like the NLB still sends requests to the site that is down which are not re-routed so there is a period in which the site appears offline before the NLB begins re-routing the requests.